# Поменять положение блоков между собой

Tags: html, html5

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="abouttoptext">
    <div class="textwin" draggable="true">
        несколько внутренних элементов
    </div>
    <div class="textwin" draggable="true">
        несколько внутренних элементов
    </div>
</div>
```

Как с помощью html5 можно реализовать перемещение блоков с классом "textwin" между собой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Спецификация](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

[Вот тут всё расжёвано](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/dnd/basics/)

[Пример](http://html5demos.com/drag)